# Do we need to Commit and Begintransaction in SELECT statements?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to MySQL. Do we need to commit or begintransaction in SELECT statements?

Suppose the query is something like this

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

So in this case do we need commit or begintransaction?

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
db.query("SELECT * FROM my_table LEFT JOIN my_table2")
```

So no we are executed to queries in case II. So in multiple queries do we need to commit or not?

I read something about the isolated state but didn't get it

Comment: no you do not need commit for select

Comment: What about begintransaction??

Comment: There are some special cases when you may need a transaction, but you probably are not using them. For example, you want to lock rows for a later update or, you may want to stream data using cursors. Safe for these [very] special cases you don't need transactions for a select.

Comment: So that means without commit and begintransaction we can execute select statements right?

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL's perspective, SELECT statements are executed straight away without using COMMIT as it requires no data-modifying action. Though statements like `INSERT, DELETE,UPDATE` do change data, manually executing COMMIT is not mandatory as MySQL has the system variable `autocommit` enabled. This variable can be verified using `show variables like 'autocommit';` and switched on/off using `set @@session.autocommit=on/off;` Usually, just leave it be.
In situations which do require manual interference regarding COMMIT, MySQL offers the use of `START TRANSACTION` statement . Once it's executed, data changing statements like `INSERT, DELETE,UPDATE` do not make actual change to the database until an explicit `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statement is run. Take this case for example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update bounty_offerers set user_reputation=user_reputation - 50 where user_name='John_the_wealthy';
update bounty_hunters set user_reputation=user_reputations + 50 where user_name='Mary_the_hunter';
call check_legitimacy() -- If the stored procedure deem the two statements illegitimate, ROLLBACK will we executed.
COMMIT;
```

In the above example, should the legitimacy check fails in the stored procedure, ROLLBACK will be executed before reaching the COMMIT statement,so the user_reputation of both users remain intact like before.

Comment: What about START TRANSACTION? Without this we can execute SELECT query??

Comment: We can execute SELECT statements without START TRANSACTION.